# What will happen if I call pthread_join() on an unused pthread_t?

Tags: c++, c, pthreads

Suppose I have a declared pthread_t struct, like the following:

```
pthread_t newThread;
```

And then I call:

```
pthread_join(&newThread, NULL, myMethod, NULL);
```

What will pthread_join() do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to ISO C, the `newThread` variable is an "indeterminately valued object", the use of which triggers undefined behavior. It could have a "trap representation" which triggers a CPU exception.

Or it may just be interpreted as a random value of that type, which the API could handle in one of two ways: either there is no such thread, and `ESRCH` is returned, or by fluke there is such a thread. Then various cases arise: is it joinable or not, etc.

Comment: Nice catch.  I didn't consider that the initial indeterminate value might just happen upon a valid thread.

Comment: *Programmers are not to be measured by their ingenuity and their logic but by the completeness of their case analysis.* Alan J. Perlis, Epigram #32.

Answer (score 2):

If you call pthread_join an an uninitialized pthread_t, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Correct: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html